# android: how do I use tabhost/tabwidget (genrally tabs) putting different activities on tabcontents

Tags: android

Firstly!,
I've used the generated `Activity` using the tab navigation type. I just used it to automatically generate `Tab` control on the `Activity`. Its on the latest *ADT*.I think :(,, 
Now my question is how do I use the `Fragments` from other `Activity` in to the `Tab` contents

secondly,
Is there any other way to put another `Activity` inside the `Tab` content which on the, lets say its MainACtivity.class?....

Planning to have 3 `Tab`s with 3 different `Activity`s, each of which contains 1 `Activity` per `tab` content

Really need ur help guys I have run out of ideas and sources :( :( ...
Kind of new to android development so be gentle. :)

Comment: i have made some changes in my answer kindly have a glance.

Comment: this tutorial might help you http://learnncode.wordpress.com/2013/12/18/how-to-use-tabwidget-with-fragments/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tab.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
         >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"/>
       <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Add below code in your activity.java file:

extend your activity by `android.app.TabActivity` instead of `Activity`

```
TabHost tabHost=getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;

    intent=new Intent().setClass(YourActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
    spec=tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("imageId").setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent=new Intent().setClass(YourActivity.this, New1Activity.class);
    spec=tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("imageId").setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

In the same way you can add as many tabs in your activity.

Comment: hmmm isn't the part tabHost = getTabHost() suppose to be findById(,,,) thing to get the tabhost?... cuz i got an error

Comment: i implemented this,its running fine.clean the project and run again it wont give u the error.if it does so than post that error

Comment: extend that activity by android.app.TabActivity instead of Activity.Than u will not get error.

Comment: ohhh nice i got it!.. tnx AkashG... by the way its already deprecated :D just sayin